# Who are these people from V for vendetta?

Tags: v-for-vendetta, alan-moore

Who are the two people each in the picture from v for vendetta? I guess the second one is gordon deitrich.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be The Leader ([Adam Susan](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Adam_Susan_(V_for_Vendetta))) and [Gordon Dietrich](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Gordon_Deitrich_(V_for_Vendetta)). Note that both of these are ridiculous, not least because Evey saw Gordon dead.

[image]

Comment: Thank U so much!!